# Quando devo utilizar as tags span,hn e p

Tags: html5

Sou novo no desenvolvimento web, e queria saber a diferença dessas tags e quando devo utiliza-las, pesquisei sobre elas mas estou com dificuldade ainda.

alguém pode me explicar de forma bem objetiva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Span**

O elemento HTML `<span>` é um conteiner generico em linha para conteúdo fraseado , que não representa nada por natureza. Ele pode ser usado para agrupar elementos para fins de estilo (usando os atributos class ou id ), ou para compartilhar valores de atributos como lang. Ele deve ser usado somente quando nenhum outro elemento semântico for apropriado. `<span>` é muito parecido com o elemento `<div>` , entretando  `<div>` é um elemento de nível de bloco enquanto `<span>` é um elemento em linha.

exemplo: `<p><span>some text</span></p>`

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

**Hn**

As Heading Tags (H1, H2, H3, ...) são recursos de programação HTML utilizados para destacar títulos e sub-títulos de uma página. H1 é a abreviação do inglês para Header 1, ou Cabeçalho 1, logo, o mais importante dos Headers. Conceitualmente, o H1 possui um destaque maior, uma fonte maior, e é geralmente o elemento de texto mais visível da página.
As demais Heading Tags, como H2 e H3, são geralmente utilizadas como sub-títulos de uma página. Em SEO, são um excelente recurso para incluir palavras-chave complementares, ou seja, variações e complementos da palavras-chave principal que não terão uma página exclusiva para ela, seja por baixo volume de pesquisa ou por simplesmente não se encaixar no conceito do site.

Exemplo:

```
<h1>Buffet Infantil da Carochinha</h1>
<h2>Festas temáticas</h2>
<h3>Festas do Barney</h3>
<h3>Festas dos Angry Birds</h3>
<h3>Festa da galinha pintadinha</h3>
<h2>Venha visitar a casa na Vila Olímpia - São Paulo</h2>
<h3>Ponto de referência</h3>
<h3>Estacionamento</h3>
```

Fonte: https://www.seomarketing.com.br/heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-seo.php

**P**

O elemento HTML `<p>` (ou Elemento HTML Parágrafo) representa um parágrafo do texto. Parágrafos são, geralmente, representados em mídia visual , como bloco de texto que são separados dos blocos adjacente por espaços brancos verticais e/ou recuo de primeira-linha.

Exemplo:

```
<p>Esse é o primeiro parágrafo do texto. Esse é o primeiro parágrafo do texto.
```

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Fiz um resumo pra você, para mais detalhes entra nas páginas que eu utilizei como fonte.

Comment: Obrigado, respondeu minha duvida. Vou dar uma olhada nesses links.

Comment: Ok, bons estudos.